# Simplest way to convert char offsets to word offsets

Tags: python, string

I have a python string and a substring of selected text. The string for example could be

```
stringy = "the bee buzzed loudly"
```

I want to select the text "bee buzzed" within this string. I have the character offsets i.e 4-14 for this particular string. Because those are the character level indices that the selected text is between.

What is the simplest way to convert these to word level indices i.e 1-2 because the second and third words are being selected. I have many strings that are labeled like this and I would like to convert the indices simply and efficiently. The data is currently stored ina  dictionary like so:

```
data = {"string":"the bee buzzed loudly","start_char":4,"end_char":14}
```

I would like to convert it to this form

```
data = {"string":"the bee buzzed loudly","start_word":1,"end_word":2}
```

Thank you!

Comment: could we get a clearer example output and what have you already tried?

Comment: sure. let me edit

Comment: `word_list  = list(stringy); selection = word_list[1:3]` like this

Comment: I dont have the word level indices. Only the character level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem like a tokenisation problem.
My solution would to use a span tokenizer and then search you substring spans in the spans.
So using the nltk library:

```
import nltk
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer()
# or tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
stringy = 'the bee buzzed loudly'
sub_b, sub_e = 4, 14  # substring begin and end
[i for i, (b, e) in enumerate(tokenizer.span_tokenize(stringy))
 if b >= sub_b and e <= sub_e]
```

But this is kind of intricate.
`tokenizer.span_tokenize(stringy)` returns spans for each token/word it identified.

Comment: that's pretty clean, might be a bit overkill but great implementation!

Answer (score 2):

Heres a simple list index approach:

```
# set up data
string  = "the bee buzzed loudly"
words = string[4:14].split(" ") #get words from string using the charachter indices
stringLst = string.split(" ") #split string into words
dictionary = {"string":"", "start_word":0,"end_word":0}


#process
dictionary["string"] = string
dictionary["start_word"] = stringLst.index(words[0]) #index of the first word in words
dictionary["end_word"] = stringLst.index(words[-1]) #index of the last
print(dictionary)
```

```
{'string': 'the bee buzzed loudly', 'start_word': 1, 'end_word': 2}
```

take note that this assumes you're using a chronological order of words inside the string

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, please;

```py
def char_change(dic, start_char, end_char, *arg):
    dic[arg[0]] = start_char
    dic[arg[1]] = end_char


data = {"string":"the bee buzzed loudly","start_char":4,"end_char":14}

start_char = int(input("Please enter your start character: "))
end_char = int(input("Please enter your end character: "))

char_change(data, start_char, end_char, "start_char", "end_char")

print(data)
```

***Default Dictionary:***

```py
data = {"string":"the bee buzzed loudly","start_char":4,"end_char":14}
```

**INPUT**

```
Please enter your start character: 1
Please enter your end character: 2
```

***OUTPUT Dictionary:***

```
{'string': 'the bee buzzed loudly', 'start_char': 1, 'end_char': 2}
```