# Finding position of a sequence of words (strings) in a sentence

Tags: regex, string, text, nlp, tokenize

I have a sentence with two markers `<e1>` and `</e1>`. I need the index of the position of the sequence of the words between these two markers. Note that the , and other possible characters are counted!

```
sent="Hi please help me to <e1>solve, this problem please</e1> Thank you."
```

What I need (the desired output):

> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

If you count each word from the beginning of the sentence, I need the index of the sequence between two markers:

```
solve -> 5  
, -> 6   
this -> 7  
problem -> 8       
please -> 9
```

I tried these two solutions:

Solution 1:

> ```
> sent="Hi please help me to <e1>solve, this problem please</e1> Thank you."
>
> E1 = re.search('<e1>(.*)</e1>', sent).group(1)
>
> sent = sent.replace('<e1>', '')
> sent = sent.replace('</e1>', '')
>
> sent = word_tokenize(sent)
>
> E1_indx = []
> E1_lis = word_tokenize(E1)
> print(E1_lis)
> for item in E1_lis:
>     E1_indx.append(sent.index(item))
>
> print(E1_indx)
> ```

But the output is:

> [5, 6, 7, 8, 1]

Solution 2:

```
sent="Hi please help me to <e1>solve, this problem please</e1> Thank you."

e1_st = re.findall(r'<e1>\w+', sent)
e1_end = re.findall(r'\w+</e1>', sent)

e1_st=(''.join(str(x) for x in e1_st))
e1_end=(''.join(str(x) for x in e1_end))

e1_st = e1_st.replace('<e1>', '')
e1_end = e1_end.replace('</e1>', '')

sent = sent.replace('<e1>', '')
sent = sent.replace('</e1>', '')

sent = word_tokenize(sent)

print(list(range(sent.index(e1_st), sent.index(e1_end)+1)))
```

Output:

> []

The problem arises when there is a repetitive word of sequence before it (here "please").

Is there any straightforward solution?

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by 'position of the sequence of the words'?

Comment: Hi, I added more info in the question!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64448665/14476967) question.

If you compute the offsets as following and remove the markers you should have the expected results.

```
sub_b = sent.find('<e1>')
sent = sent.replace('<e1>')
sub_e = sent.find('</e1>')
sent = sent.replace('</e1>')
```